# Isomorphism of Chain Complex, definition/terminology

Tags: homological-algebra

Exercise 1.1.3 of An Introduction to Homological Algebra, Charles A. Weibel states

'... show that ... every chain complex of vector spaces is isomorphic to a complex of this fom'

An isomorphism of chain complexes has not been defined yet. My hunch was that it would be a morphism that induced isomorphisms on each homology module, but then 2 paragraphs later his notion is defined as a quasi-isomorphism.

So what am I supposed to show for exercise 1.1.3? I.e what is isomorphism vs quasi isomorphism of chain complexes?

I assume what I have provided is enough context for people more familiar with homological algebra but I can state th whole question if needed.

Comment: Just an isomorphism in the category of chain complexes; so a chain map that's an isomorphism in each dimension.

Comment: Ok so they are using isomorphism and quasi isomorphism the same?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

Isomorphism always means a morphism that has an inverse morphism.

There are a number of ways to show that a morphism of chain complexes is an isomorphism if and only if its map in each degree is an isomorphism.

Comment: Can you give an example then of a quasi isomorphism that is not an isomorphism

Comment: @PrinceM Think about the complex $\dots \to 0 \to X \overset{id}{\to} X \to 0\to \dots $. Its homology is zero at every degree, so that the zero map is a quasi-automorphism. But, of course, this is not an isomorphism.